# Does Snell's Law have real life applications?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, speed-of-light, refraction

For a science experiment, I found the speed of light when travelling through various mediums. This was obtainable using Snell's Law, where v1 was the speed of light through air, and all I had to do was measure the angle of incidence and the angle of refraction, then rearrange to get the speed of light in said medium. However, I need to link this to significance in the real world. Using the speed of light in the tested medium could get me the refractive index as well. I just could not think of or find many real-life applications of Snell's Law, or refractive indexes, and I really needed help with that.

**:(**

Comment: Maybe search about optical fibre and mirages  in wiki

Comment: Making cameras?

Comment: Designing lenses? And on a related note, designing ways to cut diamonds etc to maximize internal reflections and hence brilliance.

Comment: You can use it to measure concentrations in fluids, for example, the amount of ethanol in beer.

Comment: ...or sugar in maple syrup.